# Outlook hyperlinks - Your organization’s policies are preventing us from completing this action for you. For more info, please contact your help desk

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, hyperlink

Inside Outlook, clicking on hyperlinks produces the follow error dialog:

> Your organization’s policies are preventing us from completing this
>   action for you. For more info, please contact your help desk.

Comment: Are you utilizing a company provided mailbox? If so, you should contact your help desk as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Use the registry fix under "Registry fix" on this site: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/242

Also you may or may not need to set your default browser as it may change to IE (it didn't for me).

This is the content of the registry fix file for 64 bit windows:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" -nohome"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile\shell\opennew\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.htm]
@="htmlfile"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html]
@="htmlfile"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.shtml]
@="htmlfile"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" -nohome"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile\shell\opennew\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" %1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.htm]
@="htmlfile"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.html]
@="htmlfile"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.shtml]
@="htmlfile"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.htm]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.html]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.shtml]
```

Registry changes may require privileges not granted at the workplace, in which case you can attempt to set the default browser as IE to make it work and then assign back to the desired browser, excerpt from the aforementioned link:

**Reassign a default browser in Windows**

> To recover, it often is enough to reassign a default browser via;

```
Windows 10
Start-> Settings-> System-> Default Apps

Windows 8 
Start-> type: Default Programs 
or 
Charms (Windows Logo key+C)-> Settings-> Control Panel-> Programs-> Default Programs

Windows Vista and Windows 7  Start-> Default Programs

Windows XP  Control Panel-> Set Program Access and Defaults
```

> When you have multiple browsers installed, it sometimes helps to set
>   the other browser as the default, apply the changes and then set your
>   preferred browser as the default again.
>
> If you only have a single Internet browser installed in Windows Vista,
>   Windows 7 or Windows 8, you can also deselect all the defaults for the
>   browser by pressing “Choose defaults for this program”, save the
>   changes and then select them all again. In Windows 10, this can be
>   done via the “Set defaults by app” link at the bottom of the Default
>   Apps screen.

Comment: Please also describe in the Answer text if the person needs local Administrator powers to perform the change.